# nested directives in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, directive

i have a directive with a directive inside of it. the parent directive (expandingTile) clicks to expand (by adding a CSS class animation + setting the boolean expandedTile to true), and once opened only clicking on the nested directive (detectClick) will close the expandingTile (hypothetically, by removing the CSS class animation to the parent directive expandingTile + resetting the boolean expandedTile to false).

i am confused if im approaching this problem the correct way, and how nested directives work in angular. any advice appreciated.

```
<li class="gallery-tile" expanding-tile>
    <section class="inner-tile">
        <!-- not expanded -->
        <p class="tile-title" ng-if="!expandedTile">Not Expanded</p>

        <!-- expanded -->
        <section ng-if="expandedTile">
            <p>Expanded Tile</p>
            <div id="CloseBtn" ng-click="closeTile()" detect-click="dontCloseTile()">X</div>
        </section>
    </section>
</li>

app.controller('TileCtrl', function($scope) {
     $scope.expandedTile = false;
     $scope.closeTile = function() {
         $scope.expandedTile = false;
     };
     $scope.dontCloseTile = function() {
        $scope.expandedTile = true;
     };
});

app.directive('expandingTile', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        controller: 'TileCtrl',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            elem.bind('click', function() {
                if(!elem.hasClass('expanded')){
                    elem.addClass('expanded');
                    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
                    //
                    scope.expandedTile = true;
                    scope.$apply();
                } 
            });
        }
    }   
}]);

app.directive('detectClick', ['$document', function($document){
    return {
        require: '^expandedTile',
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            elem.bind('click', function(e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
            });
            $document.bind('click', function() {
                scope.$apply(attrs.detectClick);
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

Comment: one idea would be to use elem.find() inside the expandingTile directive to find #CloseBtn see if it's been clicked, and then removeClass('expanded') to the elem as well as set expandedTile to false. but im not sure 1. how to do this (binding a click event on #CloseBtn does nothing) or 2. if this is a better approach than the one above.

Answer (score 0):

found the solution.

```
<li ng-repeat="project in projects" class="gallery-tile" ng-class="{expanded: expandedTile}" expanding-tile>
    <section class="inner-tile">
        <p ng-show="expandedTile" id="CloseBtn" ng-click="closeTile()" detect-outside-click>X</p>
    </section>
</li>

/* expanding tile */
app.directive('expandingTile', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        controller: function($scope) {
            $scope.closeTile = function(elem) {
                console.log('close tile')
                $scope.expandedTile = false;
            }
        },
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            elem.bind('click', function(e) {
                if(!elem.hasClass('expanded')){
                    scope.expandedTile = true;
                    scope.$apply();
                }
            });
        }
    }   
}]);

/* detect outside click */
app.directive('detectOutsideClick', ['$document', function($document){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            elem.bind('click', function(e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
            });
            $document.bind('click', function() {
                scope.$apply(attrs.detectOutsideClick);
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```